# Codeigniter _remap error undefined default_method

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got error default_method is not define

this is my url access

- Admin/Description/1

> for id generate from db (this work if no _remap but not work when have _remap)

- Admin/Description/update

> my public function update() (this not work if no _remap && have
>   _remap)

this is my Controller

```
public function _remap($method)
    {
        if ($method === 'update')
        {
            $this->$method();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->default_method();
        }
    }
    public function index($id = NULL)
    {
        $exits_id = $this->Description_model->get_all_id();

        if(count($exits_id) > 0)
        {
            foreach($exits_id as $exits_id):

                $id_arr[]=$exits_id->desc_id;

            endforeach;
        }

        if(!in_array($id, $id_arr))
        {
            show_404();
        }
        $viewdata['content']=$this->General_model->get_page_uri();
        $viewdata['ha']='Indroduction / '. $id.' / ';
        $this->load->view("backend/content_view",$viewdata);
    }
    public function update()
    {
        echo 'update';
    }
```

this is my Route

```
$method_arr=array(
            'Dashboard',
            'Googlemap',
            'Deccription',
            'Slideshow'
            );
foreach($method_arr as $method_arr){
    $route['Admin/'.strtolower($method_arr)] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;
    $route['Admin/'.$method_arr] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;

    $route['Admin/'.strtolower($method_arr).'/(:any)'] = 'backend/'.$method_arr.'/$1';

    $route['Admin/'.$method_arr.'/(:any)'] = 'backend/'.$method_arr.'/$1';
    /*This 1 line above read my function method */
}

$route['Admin/Description/(:any)'] = 'backend/Description/index/$1';
/*This 1 line above read my index($id = NULL) */
```

> Error :  Call to undefined method Description::default_method()

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solve Remove function _remap()

and change route that for index($id = NULL)to top of other $route

```
$route['Admin/Description/(:num)'] = 'backend/Description/index/$1';
/*This 1 line above read my index($id = NULL) */

foreach($method_arr as $method_arr){
    $route['Admin/'.strtolower($method_arr)] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;
    $route['Admin/'.$method_arr] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;

    $route['Admin/'.strtolower($method_arr).'/(:any)'] = 'backend/'.$method_arr.'/$1';

    $route['Admin/'.$method_arr.'/(:any)'] = 'backend/'.$method_arr.'/$1';
    /*This 1 line above read my function method */
}
```

but i have question how $route override other $route

- $route at Top will override every down $route ?
- $route at Down will override every Top $route ?

Answer (score 0):

I have coded with the version I need, like your problem.

I think you made the wrong `_remap`. But, thanks for your code got me to try this. It worked.

```
function _remap($param){
    if(is_numeric($param)) $this->index($param);
    else $this->$param();
}
```